# lower_bound == upper_bound

Tags: c++, math, stl, naming-conventions

What does lower_bound mean. If I had to guess I would answer that this function returns the iterator at the last element that is less than the value asked for. But I see that lower_bound is almost the same as upper_bound. The only difference is strict inequality in the case of upper_bound. Is there a true lower bound selection function in stl that agrees with the normal definition of lower bound.

EDIT: It was too many negations in the docs which made me confused. The problem was that I got the same iterator. I solved it by subtracting 1 from lower_bound return value. I use it for interpolation:

```
    float operator()(double f)
        {
        SpectrumPoint* l=std::lower_bound(beginGet(),endGet(),(SpectrumPoint){float(f),0.0f}
            ,SpectrumPoint::CompareFreqLessThan);
        if(l>beginGet())
            {--l;}

        SpectrumPoint* u=std::lower_bound(beginGet(),endGet(),(SpectrumPoint){float(f),0.0f}
            ,SpectrumPoint::CompareFreqLessThan);

        if(u==endGet())
            {u=beginGet();}

        if(l==u)
            {
            if(u==endGet())
                {return u->amp;}
            return l->amp;
            }

        double f_min=l->freq;
        double A_min=l->amp;
        double f_max=u->freq;
        double A_max=u->amp;

        double delta_f=f_max-f_min;
        double delta_A=A_max-A_min;

        return A_min + delta_A*(f-f_min)/delta_f;
        }
```

I am sorry for this confusion :-(

Comment: Are you asking why it returns the iterator *after* the bound (which is guaranteed to exist, due to the C++ convention of using half-open ranges), rather than the iterator *before* the bound (which is not guaranteed to exist)? Or do you have some other notion of where the bound should be?

Comment: I don't quite see how this is not a real question. Agreed that there are no question marks, but there seem to be some valid concerns in the text.

Comment: Yes, the name is incorrect. A better name would be `least_upper_bound`, but that would probably confuse most non-mathematically minded folk. A mathematically correct `lower_bound` function template would have to return a reverse iterator. This would be much less useful than the current scheme of returning a forward iterator to the least upper bound. The name of the function is technically incorrect, but it is still meaningful.

Comment: Please put some effort into this question: Give it a [meaningful title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145047/163768), and edit the body to phrase questions as proper English (including a question mark!). The question certainly has merit, but the poor presentation may be putting people off.

Comment: I find the title rather useful. I was in great confusion and repeating the title (but with question marks) in my head.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

- Lower bound: first element that is greater-or-equal.
- Upper bound: first element that is strictly greater.

**Example:**

```
+- lb(2) == ub(2)       +- lb(6)        +- lb(8)
|        == begin()     |  == ub(6)     |   +- ub(8) == end()
V                       V               V   V
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    ^               ^                       ^
    |               |                       |
    +- lb(4)        +- ub(4)                +- lb(9) == ub(9) == end()

    |- eq-range(4) -|
```

As you can see, the half-open equal-range for *n* is [lb(*n*), ub(*n*)).

Note that both bounds give you meaningful insertion locations for an element of the desired value so that the ordering is maintained, but `lower_bound` has the distinguishing feature that *if* the element already exists, then you get an iterator which actually points to that element. Thus you can use `lower_bound` on an ordered range to implement your own unique-membership *or* multiple-membership container.

```
void insert(Container & c, T const & t)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(c.begin(), c.end(), t);

    // if unique container:
    if (it != c.end() && *it == t) { /* error, element exists! */ return; }

    c.insert(it, t);
}
```

Comment: It just dawned on me that `lower_bound` uses the order-comparison operator (like `<`), and so the existence condition should be rewritten as `!(t < *it)` in order to not require unnecessary constraints.

Comment: There are no "between" pointers/iterators. Arrows in your diagram should point to actual elements and not between them.

Comment: @AmokHuginnsson: The arrows point to the beginning of the element which the corresponding iterator would dereference. That way I don't need to invent a fictitious past-the-end element :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, IMO, adding past-the-end element is better then missing important information that `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` returns iterators that point to some _actual_ elements. Besides, for collection of simple `int`s, what do you mean by "beginning of the element"? - some few first bits of given `int`? First bit of an `int`? or maybe whole `int`? For collection of any complex type, say `std::string`, the iterator returned by lb or ub points to first characters of the string or to the string as whole? What I say is - your diagram can be misleading.

Comment: @KerrekSB: iterators, like pointers, point to elements. In a pointer introduction course you would not draw an array of memory slots and then have a pointer arrow point _in between_ the cells, would you? We can discuss the best way to display the case of an `end()` iterator not pointing to an actual element of the array (Should it point nowhere? Should it point at the one-past-last element?), but I doubt that the best way to handle this case is to say "we'll just have all itererators point to the edges between cells instead of at the actual cells".

Comment: @KerrekSB: (cont.) That would force the reader to mentally redraw the arrows pointing between cells to point at the following cell -- which leaves him to mentally add the ficticious one-past-last element anyway.

Comment: @ChristianSeverin: Would it make you happier to think of the cell as starting at its boundary, rather than at the (arbitrary) location of its label? There is no "in between spaces".

Comment: @KerrekSB: The question is not "how can _I_ look at the diagram to make me happy?" These iterator arrows _should point at the locations they're actually pointing at_ -- or, in the case of the `end()` iterator, it should be "(...) pointing to the past-the-end element in the sequence" ([definition of std::end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/)).

Comment: @KerrekSB: This virtual "past-the-end element" is canon, it's referenced everywhere, and it's not a concept people should be shielded from by _repointing pointer arrows_.

Comment: Christian seemed a little overly passionate about his view, but I agree that this diagram would be easier to understand if the arrows pointed directly at the elements they dereference.  The arrow for ub(4) pointing to the right edge of [4] gives a misleading connection to the end of the equal range of 4s which would be inaccessible from the iterator in a collection that is only forward-iterable and is not what the return value of upper_bound is about.

Comment: Thinking of iterators as a valid location for insertion of a new element, it makes good sense for the iterators to point in between elements or better in front of an element as depicted.

Comment: @YoungJohn: Thank you for pointing that out! I have always felt that this depiction was useful to me, but I've never consciously connected it with insertion. Indeed, "insert at an iterator" has always been something I need to think about twice.

Comment: @KerrekSB What tool did you use to draw that diagram? Or was it "manually" drawn?

Answer (score 9):

Since this has been reopened, I'll try to make my comment an answer.

The name `lower_bound` is mathematically incorrect. A better name might be `least_upper_bound`, but that would probably confuse most non-mathematically minded folk. (And then what do you call `upper_bound`? `almost_least_upper_bound`? Yech!)

My advice: Get over the fact that the names `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are technically incorrect. The two functions as defined are quite useful. Think of those functions as a useful abuse of notation.

To make a mathematically correct `lower_bound` function that conforms with the C++ concept of an iterator, the function would have to return a reverse iterator rather than a forward iterator. Returning a reverse iterator is not nearly as useful as the approach taken by the perhaps misnamed `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, and the concept of returning a reverse iterator runs afoul of the fact that not all containers are reversible.

Why a reverse iterator? Just as there is no guarantee that an upper bound exists in the container, there similarly is no guarantee that a lower bound will exist. The existing `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` return `end()` to indicate that the searched-for value is off-scale high. A true lower bound would need to return `rend()` to indicate that the searched-for value is off-scale low.

There is a way to implement a true lower bound in the form of a forward iterator, but it comes at the price of abusing the meaning of `end()` to mean "there is no lower bound". The problem with this abuse of notation is that some user of the function might do something equivalent to `true_lower_bound(off_scale_low_search_value)-1` and voila! one has a pointer to the largest element in the set.

That said, here's how to do it. Have the true lower bound function return `end()` if the container is empty or if the searched-for value is smaller than the first value in the container. Otherwise return `upper_bound()-1`.

Comment: I don't see why the names `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are necessarily incorrect. The meaning is clear for me: for any value x, they give the lower and upper bounds of the range where you can insert x and not break the order of the given range. Or alternatively, all values in [begin, lower_bound) are less than x, values in [lower_bound, upper_bound) are equal to x, and [upper_bound, end) are greater than x.

Comment: Full set of good names is implemented in Java - {ceiling,floor,lower,higher}Entry() and, another, but still good, in C5 library for C# - [Weak]{Predecessor,Successor}. But they are devoted to the practical map search itself, not an abstract mathematical iterating concept around an abstract sequence.

Comment: @musiphil I explained why by making an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56770542/893406

Answer (score 8):

It returns the iterator one past the last element that is less than the value asked for. This is useful as an insertion position (and that's why the function returns that iterator). It's also useful that the half-open range `first, lower_bound(first, last, value)` specifies all values less than `value`.

`upper_bound` returns the iterator one past the last element [less than or equal to  / not greater than] the value asked for. Or strictly: the last element which the value is not less than, since both algorithms deal exclusively in less-than comparators.

If you want the iterator before the iterator returned by `lower_bound`, you can subtract 1 (for a random access iterator), decrement (for a bidirectional iterator), or do a linear search instead of using `lower_bound` (for a forward iterator that is none of those).

Beware the edge case that there is no element less than the value asked for, in which case you can't have what you want, because it doesn't exist. `lower_bound` of course returns the beginning of the range in that case, so doesn't need a special-case return value.

Comment: *"`lower_bound` of course returns the beginning of the range in that case"* << This bit is wrong: `std::lower_bound` returns the *end* of the range if the element doesn't exist. (and `std::upper_bound` does the same).

Comment: @Nawaz I think he means the case where `lower_bound == begin()`

Answer (score 2):

`lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` are functions which perform binary search in a sorted sequence.  The need for three functions comes from the fact that elements may be repeated in the sequence:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

In this case, when searching for the value 4, `lower_bound` will return an iterator pointing to the first of the three elements with value 4, `upper_bound` will return an iterator pointing to the element with value 5, and `equal_range` will return a pair containing these two iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Following David Hammen's answer, I attempted to explain why we often don't feel the names of `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` to be correct, or at least intuitive.

It's because we are looking for an element immediately lower than the query.
I made a drawing and a use case:

[image: sparse range queries]

Code:

```
template< typename T, typename U >
auto infimum(std::map<T,U> const& ctr, T query)
{
    auto it = ctr.upper_bound(query);
    return it == ctr.begin() ? ctr.cend() : --it;
}

template< typename T, typename U >
bool is_in_interval(std::map<T,U> const& ctr, T query)
{
    auto inf = infimum(ctr, query);
    return inf == ctr.end() ? false : query <= inf->second;
}
```

https://ideone.com/jM8pt3

Basically to get the behavior of the "grey arrows", we need `upper_bound - 1` which is why it's weird.

*Let me rephrase that slightly:* from the name `lower_bound` we instinctively expect `returns-first-immediately-inferior-element` (like the grey arrows). But we get `returns-first-immediately-superior-element` for lower_bound; and `first-immediately-strictly-superior-element` for upper_bound. That's what is surprising.

It's surprising in the hypothesis that you work with a *sparse sequence* like my thought experiment in the picture above. But it makes wonderful sense when you think of it in terms of «bounds of an `equal_range`» in a *dense sequence*, populated with plateaus, like Kerrek SB beautifully pictured.

Test code:

```
#include <map>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

// .. paste infimum and is_in_interval here

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using Map = std::map<int,int>;
    Map intervals{{2,5}, {8,9}};

    auto red = infimum(intervals, 4);
    assert(red->first == 2);
    cout << "red->first " << red->first << "\n";

    auto green = infimum(intervals, 6);
    assert(green->first == 2);
    cout << "green->first " << green->first << "\n";

    auto pink = infimum(intervals, 8);
    assert(pink->first == 8);
    cout << "pink->first " << pink->first << "\n";

    auto yellow = infimum(intervals, 1);
    assert(yellow == intervals.cend());

    auto larger_than_all = infimum(intervals, 15);
    assert(larger_than_all->first == 8);

    bool red_is = is_in_interval(intervals, 4);
    cout << "red is in " << red_is << "\n";

    bool green_is = is_in_interval(intervals, 6);
    cout << "green is in " << green_is << "\n";

    bool pink_is = is_in_interval(intervals, 8);
    cout << "pink is in " << pink_is << "\n";

    bool yellow_is = is_in_interval(intervals, 1);
    cout << "yellow is in " << yellow_is << "\n";
}
```

results in

```
red->first 2
green->first 2
pink->first 8
red is in 1
green is in 0
pink is in 1
yellow is in 0
```

seems ok.

So of course the utility functions are not very good, they should be designed with a range API, so we can work with any collection or sub-range, or reverse iterators, or filtered views and whatnot. We can get that when we have C++20. In the meantime, I just made a simple educative map-taking API.

play with it:
https://ideone.com/jM8pt3

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. To begin with, why are you using `std::map<int, int>` to represent a set of intervals (which I believe should be something like `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>`)? Do the upper endpoints 5 and 9 in `intervals` have any significance?
And what is `infimum(c, q)` supposed to mean? I understand the infimum of a set in mathematics, but is there a widely accepted definition of the infimum of a set and a query point?

Comment: @musiphil all excellent sounding questions; the `pair` stuff offers a bit more flexibility that I didn't need in that particular example, no strong reason. And yes 5 and 9 have significance, I'm testing against "0,1,inf". It's a sort of recurrence proofing, the 5 is far away enough from 2 to test "inf" and the 9 is just 1 away from 8 so it tests "1". So indeed the function `infimum` is based the math definition, but loosely. I thought it would be enough to separate from the "lower_bound" terminology to fix the issue pointed by Hammem.

Answer (score 1):

Another usage of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` is to find a range of equal elements in a container, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> data = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 };

auto lower = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 4);
auto upper = std::upper_bound(lower, data.end(), 4);

std::copy(lower, upper, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: `equal_range` does that too, and at least shouldn't be slower than calling both `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

Comment: in your example, wouldn't it make more sense to start the search for upper bound from `lower` instead of `data.begin()`?

Answer (score 1):

Auch!

Did you change the original code or is the copy-paste error in there since day one?

```
float operator()(double f)
{
    SpectrumPoint* l=std::lower_bound//...
...
    SpectrumPoint* u=std::lower_bound//...
...
}
```

In the code I read today you are assigning lower_bound to both 'l' and 'u'.