# C++ map erase(begin, end) not working

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to do my life easier by using the C++ API for map. Through the `map.erase(begin, end)` method I'm hoping to delete all the entries between `[begin, end)`. So my method is implemented and
`TabletKey` are defined below.

```
 79 void
 80 ObjectFinder::flush(uint64_t tableId) {
 81 
 82     RAMCLOUD_TEST_LOG("flushing object map");
 83     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator lower;
 84     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator upper;
 85     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator it;
 86     KeyHash keyHash = Key::getHash(tableId, "", 0);
 87     TabletKey key(tableId, keyHash);
 88 
 89     std::cout << "before the loop" << std::endl;
 90     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); it++) {
 91         std::cout << it->first.first << std::endl;
 92     }
 93     lower = tableMap.lower_bound(key);
 94     upper = tableMap.upper_bound(key);
 95     
108     tableMap.erase(lower, upper);
109     std::cout << "After the erase" << std::endl;
110     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); it++) {
111         std::cout << it->first.first << std::endl;
112     }
    }
```

However, the `id` values are not being deleted:

```
id = 99
before the loop
1
99
After the erase
1
99
```

I wrote my own `comparison` function, to overload the default method:

```
 35 typedef std::pair<uint64_t, KeyHash> TabletKey;
 36 
 37 /*
 38  * The object CmpTabletKey is used to override the default comparison 
 39  * definition from the C++ Map.
 40  */
 41 struct CmpTabletKey {
 42     bool operator()(const TabletKey& key1, const TabletKey& key2) const {
 43         return ((key1.first < key2.first) ||
 44                 (key1.first == key2.first && key1.second < key2.second));
        }
    }
```

Could someone give me a clue why is `erase` not working as expected? Do I have to give the definition of `CmpTabletKey` to the `iterator` as well?
***Update***
This is my old implementation: It works nicely, and do what I want:
However, it's a O(n) method, and I want a faster implementation:

```
117     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator it;
118     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); ) {
119         if (tableId == it->first.first) {
120             tableMap.erase((it++)->first);
121         } else {
122             ++it;
123         }
124     }
```

Comment: it's a `C++` map between a `TabletKey` and an object

Comment: Why are you blaming `erase`? Did you even check that the iterators have the expected values?

Comment: @maditya since he says `std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator it = tableMap.begin()`, I can only assume it is a `std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I did check the iterators ... I would like to know if I'm doing the right thing thou

Comment: @philippe if you put a `printf()` statement in your `CmpTabletKey`, does it actually get called?

Comment: Are the two iterators equal by chance?

Comment: @KerrekSB they are equal ..because the tableId is `10`, and the map has tableId `1`

Comment: @Aggieboy I will do it and let you know

Comment: So... have you read *any* manuals to try and understand what `erase` does?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes sir: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/

Comment: If you want to erase all elements with the key value key, you should simply write tableMap.erase(key);

Comment: @dieram3 it's a double value key ... some of them may have the same `tableId` but different keyhashes ...

Comment: OK, make sure you also understand what upper bound and lower bound do, e.g. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12159150/596781). If they're equal, then the key doesn't exist, and the iterator value is where the element *would* be inserted.

Comment: You need to specify CmpTabletKey as part of the type of the map:
`std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey > tableMap;`

Comment: @maditya I did it too

Comment: Do you understand the range notation that you used?  If `begin == end`, then `[begin,end)` is an empty set.

Comment: what does Key::getHash(tableId, "", 0); return?

Comment: @philippe: Wait, are you wanting to delete all of the keys who's .first == 99, regardless of their second parts? I GET IT NOW

Comment: @dieram3: I want to delete all the entries in `tabletMap` that has `id==tableId`. I've updated my answer ...

Comment: @MooingDuck That's exactly what I want .. did you see the old implementation how it was done?

Comment: @KerrekSB I added the old implementation that worked ... I want to remove all the entries that has `tableId` regardless of their second parts.

Comment: @philippe So I've already proven myself inept, but if the comparison also checks the `key.second` value, isn't that a tad different from what the original was doing?

Comment: @Aggieboy True ... as in that case I only case about the `tableId`, so I shouldn't use the `key.second`?

Comment: You cannot use the member `lower_bound` function in that case, because that uses the map's own comparator. You also can't sensibly use the free `std::lower_bound` algorithm, because that requires the range to be sorted according to the comparator. You might get away with making an auxiliary container of map iterators and sort and select *that* one. (Though I believe that you probably just designed your map suboptimally.)

Comment: @philippe That'd be my guess.  Try just `return key1.first < key2.first;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you give me more detail?

Comment: About what part specifically?

Comment: @KerrekSB When I defined the `tableMap` I gave the `CmpTabletKey` in the declaration of the map. Doesn't don't override the comparator being used in `map::lower_bound`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Could show me how would I implement it?

Comment: That's certainly the case (and by the way utterly pointless, since `pair` *already* defines lexicographic comparison), but it simply means that it's much harder to apply some *other* ordering to the table, as you appear to want to do.

Comment: @KerrekSB Should I just stick with the older implementation then?

Answer (score 4):

From how your iterators are defined, it appears you are not creating the map with your custom-defined comparator.

I believe the map should be created as:

```
std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey > tableMap; //CmpTabletKey is passed as the comparator type

And your iterators become: 
std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey>::iterator lower;
std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey>::iterator upper;
std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey>::iterator it;
```

If you don't specify `CmpTabletKey` as the type, your map will use the default comparator.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/value_comp/), the important lines to note are `Compare comp;` and `value_compare (Compare c) : comp(c) {}`, where `Compare` is the 3rd template argument as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Considering `CmpTabletKey` is functionally equivalent to the default, I don't believe this isn't the source of his problem...

Comment: @MooingDuck As `TabletKey` is a double key, then I need to define what is `less` in that case

Comment: @philippe: No you don't.  Proof: Your code compiled, ran, and did the _exact same things_ with and without your custom comparitor object.

Comment: @philippe: `operator<` works with `std::pair` right out of the box, as long as both the first and the second member can be compared that way. And its behavior is exactly as you defined in your custom comparator, a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: @MooingDuck did you find a possible solution?

Comment: @philippe: Yes, use a map of maps instead of a double key.

Answer (score 3):

The map container mantains at most one copy of each key, I think what you want to do is erase all element where TableID is the same, but you have ordered your elements using a pair, so you would have to iterate all the map and select the elements that meet the predicate.

If you can, you should use std::multimap and create a comparer where only TableID is involved.

**EDIT:**

Well so you want to erase all elements with a specific ID. But indeed what your map is looking for is an element with a specific tableID and a specific keyHash.

You have several solutions, one of these is O(n) (the solution that you have), another option, is to use another data structure, that meets your requiriments. I think you should use a multimap or an unordered_multimap (hast_table).

Comment: Or a map of maps or something

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example that should help you achieve your goal.

Let's make a map with a pair key:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<int, int> key_type;

std::map<key_type, void *> mymap = { { { 1, 2}, NULL }
                                   , { { 5, 0}, NULL }
                                   , { { 5, 7}, NULL }
                                   , { { 6, 3}, &mymap } };
```

Now suppose we want to remove all elements from `mymap` whose *first* key part is equal to `5`. Here's one solution:

```
for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); )
{
    if (it->first.first == 5) { mymap.erase(it++); }
    else                      { ++it;              }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take 2...  Since your original does not even consider the `key.second` value, I'm guess that the problem is in the `CmpTabletKey`, but for a different reason this time.  The functionally equivalent comparison operator to the original implementation is:

```
 35 typedef std::pair<uint64_t, KeyHash> TabletKey;
 36 
 37 /*
 38  * The object CmpTabletKey is used to override the default comparison 
 39  * definition from the C++ Map.
 40  */
 41 struct CmpTabletKey {
 42     bool operator()(const TabletKey& key1, const TabletKey& key2) const {
 43         return (key1.first < key2.first);
        }
    }
```

I suspect that since your current implementation also takes into consideration the `.second` value, then the functionality as changed from the original.  Erasing everything between a lower bound and upper bound of the same objection essentially erases all keys equivalent to that object, however you have `KeyHash keyHash = Key::getHash(tableId, "", 0);` and `TabletKey key(tableId, keyHash);`, but the key value of `key` is not specifically in your map.  Your compare operator is *too* specific, so it won't evaluate the equivalence of just the `.first` value.

At the same time, it is necessary for the comparison to be that strict because I *believe* the map search basically says "if A !< B and B !< A, then A == B".  This means that you won't be able to insert values properly because equivalence would also not care about the `.second`.  I don't think your current implementation will work because of these conflicting definitions.

Edit:  Derp.  Try this:

```
 79 void
 80 ObjectFinder::flush(uint64_t tableId) {
 81 
 82     RAMCLOUD_TEST_LOG("flushing object map");
 83     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator lower;
 84     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator upper;
 85     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::iterator it;
 86     //KeyHash keyHash = Key::getHash(tableId, "", 0);
        TabletKey keylower(tableId, KeyHash::MINIMUM);
        TabletKey keyupper(tableId, KeyHash::MAXIMUM);
 87     //TabletKey key(tableId, keyHash);
 88 
 89     std::cout << "before the loop" << std::endl;
 90     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); it++) {
 91         std::cout << it->first.first << std::endl;
 92     }
 93     lower = tableMap.lower_bound(keylower);
 94     upper = tableMap.upper_bound(keyupper);
 95     
108     tableMap.erase(lower, upper);
109     std::cout << "After the erase" << std::endl;
110     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); it++) {
111         std::cout << it->first.first << std::endl;
112     }
    }
```

Where `KeyHash::MINIMUM` is a static const of the lowest key hash value, and `KeyHash::MAXIMUM` is the max.  Use your current comparison struct.