# C++ map key/iterator manipulation

Tags: c++, dictionary

Given a

> `map<int,string>`

for example, knowing that the key can be a value from 0 to 1.000.000 , but not all are set, is it possible for a given key X to jump to the nearest key/iterator ?
I'm basically looking for a way to find the nearest value without having to iterate over all the keys.

Example:

```
map<int,string> dict;
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(1,"smth"));
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(2,"smth"));
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(100,"smth"));
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(1000,"smth"));
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(7777,"smth"));
dict.insert(pair<int,string>(9999,"smth"));

//this should jump to key/value <7777,"smth">
get_magic_match(5000,dict);
```

Comment: Why not check the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `std::map`'s [**`lower_bound`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound).

It returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than a given key.

Comment: Almost perfect but if I have for example a pair <4999,"smth">, and I search for 5000, the result will be the <7777,"smth"> pair instead of the closer one with 4999, any way to work around this ?

Comment: @Alex After using `lower_bound`, compare the element at the iterator to the one before it, and choose the closest one to your desired value. Make sure to check whether the iterator equals `begin`, because then you mustn't check if anything is before it.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `lower_bound/upper_bound` operations made available by std::map..

`upper_bound` returns an iterator to the first element in the container whose key is considered to go after k, or map::end if no keys are considered to go after k.

`lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element in the container whose key is not considered to go before k, or map::end if all keys are considered to go before k.

Actually, the names lower_bound and upper_bound are not mathematically in sync with what their name suggests.

[lower and upper bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158948/lower-bound-upper-bound)

Comment: Almost perfect @basav but if I have for example a pair <4999,"smth">, and I search for 5000, the result will be the <7777,"smth"> pair instead of the closer one with 4999, any way to work around this ?

Comment: with these operations, there is no such thing as nearest value unless you mention it...you choose lower_bound/ upper_bound based on whether you want the first key lesser than 5000/greater than 5000...

Comment: from what I understand lower_bound returns the key which "is not considered to go before k (i.e., either it is equivalent or goes after)." so it's not the first less than 5000

Comment: it's a long explanation, explained brilliantly in attached link