# Accessing pair-vector to return using iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, operator-overloading

my task is to overload the `[]` operator and use `girl[index] = partner` to write stuff into a pair vector:

```
class Dancers {
    unsigned long & operator [] (int i);
    vector<pair<int,string>> m_dancers;
};
unsigned long & operator [] (int i) {
    auto iter = lower_bound(m_dancers.first.begin(), m_dancers.first.end(), i, cmpInt);
    m_dancers.first.insert(iter, i);
    //what now?
}     
int main() {
    Pairs girl;
    girl[0] = "Richard";

    return 0;
}
```

So I've managed to sort the girls and now I have the girl that I want to assign a partner to. From what I understand, now it's time to return the reference so I can assign the partner. How do I do that using the iterator?

And MORE IMPORTANTLY: is there a more efficient way to assign `x` and `y` to a pair-vector in a `a[x] = y` situation? Or am I trying to reinvent a wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you *don't* want to insert a new element if there is already an existing key in your map (i.e. you want a unqiue-key map, not a multi-key map). So you need to check the key and only insert conditionally. And you want to return the *mapped* element, not they key.

```
string & operator[](int key) {
    auto it = lower_bound(m_dancers.begin(), m_dancers.end(), key, cmpInt);

    if (it->first != key)
        it = m_dancers.insert(it, make_pair(i, string()));

    return it->second;
}
```

If you wanted a multi-key map instead, then just omit the conditional check and make the insertion unconditionally. (But then you'd probably want to use `upper_bound` so that new elements are added at the *end* of their equal-range, also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12159150).)

To summarize, things that needed to be fixed in your code:

- Return type
- Iterators are from the vector, not from the pair
- Insertion is conditional
- Remember the result of the insertion
- You misspelled your use case, it should say `Dancers girl;`
- You are probably misspelling the out-of-line member definition; it should say `string & Dancers::operator[](int i)`... (or just define it inline).

Comment: With these edits, my simple int comparator won't work so how do I fix the comparator?