# lower bound upper bound giving same results

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, lower-bound

I'm trying to find the nearest value in an sorted array, but both upper_bound and lower_bound are giving the highest value.

```
float abc[] = {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

float *a  = lower_bound(abc, abc+8, 3.2);
cout<< *a;

return 0;
```

Comment: [`std::lower_bound` Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). Seems like `4` is the expected number.

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158948/lower-bound-upper-bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*a` will be 4 in both cases, as the value pointed to by `a` would be `3.2` if that was inserted correctly into the container.

`lower_bound` and `upper_bound` will return the same iterator if the value passed is not present in the container, which is the case here.

The iterator returned by `lower_bound` is defined to be the lowest position where the element passed could reside it was in the container, `higher_bound` returns the highest position. They do **not** return anything related to the *closest* element present in the array.

In order to find the closest element, you know that the dereferenced result of `lower_bound` is greater than or equal to the value passed. The value before that, if any, must be less. You can make use of this in order to arrive at the closest value.

Comment: is there anything in c++ to find the nearest element.

Comment: @aja: Not at the time of writing no; I've added a final paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

As the value 3.2 is absent in the array then the both algorithms `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` will return the same iterator.

In such a case you should consider a previous iterator.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    float abc[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    float value = 3.2f;

    auto it = std::lower_bound( std::begin( abc ), std::end( abc ), value );

    auto closest = it;

    if ( it == std::end( abc ) )
    {
        closest = std::prev( it );
    }
    else if ( it != std::begin( abc ) )
    {
        closest = std::min( std::prev( it ), it, 
                            [&value]( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 )
                            {
                                return abs( value - *p1 ) < abs( value - *p2 );
                            } );
    }

    std::cout << *closest << " at position " << std::distance( std::begin( abc ), closest ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3 at position 1
```

Comment: what is the purpose of f in float value = 3.2f; ?

Comment: @aja It is a float literal. Without f it will be a double literal.