# Binary search to find less or equal value in STL C++ multiset

Tags: c++, binary-search, multiset

We have STL (Standard Template Library) multiset, we want to implement a binary search that will give us the first less-or-equal element compared to some value x

From this post: [lower_bound == upper_bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158948/lower-bound-upper-bound), we see that we can use the standar lower_bound and upper_bound to find greater values compared to x, what about finding smaller or equal.

Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: Binary search doesn't work with multiset or any other associative container.

Comment: *"first less-or-equal element"* -- This would always be the first element of the range (i.e. `set.begin()`) except in the case that all the elements are greater than x, in which case it's not clear what you would want returned.

Comment: @n.m. where are you getting that from? According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/), they are commonly implemented as binary search trees. And they have a logarithmic complexity find method. Perhaps you were thinking of an unordered_multiset?

Comment: @Helium_1s2 Binary search doesn't work with associative containers. whatever their implementation is and whatever its underlying complexity is. They may well be using binary search as internal implementation technique, it is immaterial. *You* can't use binary search with them. They simply don't have an API that would support binary search.

Comment: @Bejamin Lindley, I wasn't thinking of that, I mean the greatest less-or-equal element. BTW, multiset is some type of binary tree that supports the standard lower_bound and upper_bound. More reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/lower_bound/

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `upper_bound` member function of the `multiset`.  `upper_bound` will return the first element that is grater than the value you are searching for.  That means the iterator before that will be the first element that is equal to or smaller than the value. So in

```
int main()
{
    std::multiset<int> ms = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5};
    auto end = ms.upper_bound(3);
    for (auto it = ms.begin(); it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << *it;
}
```

It will print `112233` since that is all the element less than or equal to `3`.

---

Of course you will need to make sure `upper_bound` does not return `begin()` which would mean there are no elements less than or equal to what you are searching for.